# Linear Approximation: How do you find the linear approximation of $2.99\sqrt{3.99}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've tried solving this by using the $L(x) = f(x) + f'(x)dx$ solution, but I can't seem to get the equation right. I'm confused about whether I should choose between $2.99$ or $3.99$. The equation I've come up with is $x-1\sqrt{x}$ where I make $x = 4$

Comment: You need parentheses in your equation: $f(x)=(x-1)\sqrt{x}.$ [then you are approximating $f(x-h)$ where $h=0.01.$]

Comment: What is your definition of a linear approximation of a constant ? I think that you should have asked your question for an expression such as $(3-x)\sqrt{4-x}$ containing a variable $x$ for small values of $x$...

Answer (score 2):

You can use either $f(x) = x\sqrt{x+1}$ or $g(x)=(x-1)\sqrt{x}.$ Do you see which number you should use for each choice?

Answer (score 1):

It's $(3-x)(4-x)^{1/2}$ with $x=0.01$. And
$(4-x)^{1/2}=2(1-x/4)^{1/2}\approx 2(1-x/8)$.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Making the problem more general, consider
$$A=(a-\epsilon)\sqrt{b-\epsilon}$$ and use Taylor series to obtain
$$A=a \sqrt{b}-\frac{ a+2 b}{2 \sqrt{b}}\,\epsilon +O\left(\epsilon
   ^2\right)$$ whose error is
$$\frac{ (4 b-a)}{8 b^{3/2}} \epsilon ^2$$

So, if $a=3$ and $b=4$
$$2.99\sqrt{3.99} \sim \frac{2389}{400}=\color{red}{5.9725}00$$ for an error of $\frac{13}{640000}$.

Notice that
$$2.99\sqrt{3.99}=5.9725203\qquad \text{and that} \qquad \frac{13}{640000}=0.0000203$$

**Edit**  *for your curiosity*

At very low cost, you could do much better if, instead of using Taylor series, you use the simplest corresponding Padé approximant.

This would give
$$A=a \sqrt{b}-\frac {2 \sqrt{b} \, (a+2 b)^2 \, \epsilon}{4 b (a+2 b) +(4b-a)\,\epsilon}$$ whose error is
$$\frac{-a^2-8 a b+24 b^2}{32 b^{5/2} (a+2 b)}\,\epsilon^3$$

Applied to your case, this would give
$$2.99\sqrt{3.99} \sim 6-\frac{484}{17613}=\color{red}{5.972520}2975$$ corresponding to an absolute error of $2.48 \times 10^{-8}$.